# Como recuperar datos en Firebase Realtime Database usando Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, http-get, realtime-database

En firebase tengo datos de usuarios que necesito llamar mediante `http.get(_uri)` y mi código es el siguiente:

```
final _uri = Uri.parse(
          "https://kaaj-reset-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=" +
              decodedResp["idToken"] +
              "&orderByChild='uid'&equalTo='" +
              decodedResp["localId"] +
              "'"); //url arbol de usuarios

      http.Response respuesta = await http.get(_uri);
      print(respuesta.body);

      Map<String, dynamic> userResponse = json.decode(respuesta.body);
```

El error que me da es:

`"error" : "orderBy must be defined when other query parameters are defined"` y no recibo los datos de mi árbol de usuarios

[image: captura del árbol de usuarios]

he tratado de probar eliminando el **auth** ,**ByChild**, **&equalTo** pero no soluciono nada, si elimino el error tras remover alguno de los paramentos ya mencionados sigo sin recibir nada de firebase. no se que me falta o me sobra. soy principiante así que disculpen si he recalcado lo obvio sin darme cuenta. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es un problema del [parámetro `orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering):

> Los datos filtrados se muestran sin orden: Cuando usas la API de REST,
> los resultados filtrados se muestran en un orden indefinido, ya que
> los intérpretes de JSON no imponen ningún orden. Si el orden de tus
> datos es importante, debes ordenar los resultados en la aplicación
> después de recibirlos de Firebase.

Prueba con `orderBy` mejor porque no existe en `orderByChild` vía REST. En Dart puedes interpolar ristras así, para mi es mas legible y ayuda a encontrar posibles errores:

```
    var url = 'https://kaaj-reset-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=${decodedResp["idToken"]}&orderBy="uid"&equalTo="${decodedResp["localId"]}"';
    final _uri = Uri.parse(url);
```

Recuerda que para hacer una ordenación [debe haber un índice asociado para ese campo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-defining-indexes).

Ten en cuenta el aviso que dice arriba, las ordenaciones NO se hacen cuando se usa REST y solo funcionan cuando lleva incluido `limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, `startAt`, `endAt` o `equalTo`, esto significa que realmente la ordenación la tienes que hacer tu una vez obtengas los resultados.

Si quieres [ordenar por la clave de la colección](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-ordered-data) debes usar `orderBy="$key"`.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, al ejecutarlo como me haz sugerido me da el error:
"error" : "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"

y sigue sin traerme los datos de firebase, ciertamente no se que es lo que le falta, te agradeceré mucho si puedes darme tu opinión, de antemano gracias por responder.

Comment: prueba a ordenar por "name" por ejemplo a ver si funciona, parece poco útil ordenar por uid, no crees?

Comment: Recuerda que para poder hacer una ordenación por un campo, este campo debe tener un índice asociado.

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas, me han ayudado bastante. en teoría ya funciona. el asunto fueron también las comillas, al parecer tenían que estar al revés:

`var fixedUrl =
          'https://kaaj-reset-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=${decodedResp["idToken"]}&orderBy="uid"&equalTo="${decodedResp["localId"]}"';
      print(fixedUrl);
      final _uri = Uri.parse(fixedUrl);`

Comment: Genial! Si crees que la respuesta ha sido útil, no te olvides de marcarla para los próximos que tengan el mismo problema.